# Locate and SortBy on the same line in Pandas

Tags: pandas, sorting, where-clause

First Post Here!

This should be incredible easy...as this is basic for SQL

My goal is to create one Pandas script that:

1. Selects Specific Columns from Table
2. Applys Where Clause to Column
3. Sorts Table

***Simple DataFrame***

| Customer | IssueCode | Count | Random |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 5 | xxx |
| 2 | Y | 5 | xxx |
| 3 | Z | 10 | xxx |

**Sql Query:** (SQL Query One Script)

Select CustomerId, IssueCode, Count 
From DataFram 
where Count= 5
sortby CustomerId

**??Pandas Script?? :**

#Apply Select Columns 
select_columns =df.loc[:,["CustomerId","IssueCode","Count "]]
select_columns

#Apply Where Clause
where_clause = select_columns.where(select_columns.Count == 5)
where_clause

#Apply Sort Clause
sort_clause=whereclause.sort_values(by=['CustomerId'], ascending=False)
sort_clause

This works but seems to extensive!!
Is this really how we would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all operations back-to-back in a single statement

```
result_df = (
    df[df.Count == 5] #filter
    .sort_values(by='CustomerId', ascending=False) #sort
    [["CustomerId","IssueCode","Count"]] #subset columns
)
```